# Como puedo crear una cuenta dentro de un contrato

Tags: solidity

Necesito crear cuentas para usarlas con alguna billetera dentro de un contrato inteligente.

La idea es crear una función que cree esas cuentas, pero no se como ejecutar web3 en el contrato. Algo así quiero hacer

```js
function createAccount() public view returns (address) {
    return web3.personal.newAccount("password");
}
```

Les agredeceria mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crear una cuenta de *Ethereum* dentro de un contrato, tiene un alto costo.

Puedes leer el [yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf), en donde se indica que cuantas más instrucciones ejecute la *EVM*, mayor será el costo de ejecutar esa transacción en la red. ¿Evaluaste eso para determinar que obligatoriamente tienes que crear una cuenta dentro de un contrato?

Una alternativa es crear la cuenta fuera de la cadena. Luego, cargarla en un contrato. Podrías usar para ello `web3`.

```
var Web3 = require("web3");
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545'); // your geth
var account = web3.eth.accounts.create();
```